# Doctrine - orm:schema-tool:create - How to ignore tables that already exist?

Tags: php, mysql, orm, doctrine-orm

I need to create a few new tables in my database, so I run `orm:schema-tool:create` and it created the first table, but then tried to create a table that already exists and the script stopped running. Heres the error message it outputs:

```
  [Doctrine\ORM\Tools\ToolsException]
  Schema-Tool failed with Error 'An exception occurred while executing 'CREATE TABLE autogen_structures (id INT AUTO_
  INCREMENT NOT NULL, structure_id INT DEFAULT NULL, INDEX FK_STRUCTURES_TO_AUTOGEN_STRUC (structure_id), PRIMARY KEY
  (id)) DEFAULT CHARACTER SET utf8 COLLATE utf8_unicode_ci ENGINE = InnoDB':
  SQLSTATE[42S01]: Base table or view already exists: 1050 Table 'autogen_structures' already exists' while executing
   DDL: CREATE TABLE autogen_structures (id INT AUTO_INCREMENT NOT NULL, structure_id INT DEFAULT NULL, INDEX FK_STRU
  CTURES_TO_AUTOGEN_STRUC (structure_id), PRIMARY KEY(id)) DEFAULT CHARACTER SET utf8 COLLATE utf8_unicode_ci ENGINE
  = InnoDB



  [Doctrine\DBAL\Exception\TableExistsException]
  An exception occurred while executing 'CREATE TABLE autogen_structures (id INT AUTO_INCREMENT NOT NULL, structure_i
  d INT DEFAULT NULL, INDEX FK_STRUCTURES_TO_AUTOGEN_STRUC (structure_id), PRIMARY KEY(id)) DEFAULT CHARACTER SET utf
  8 COLLATE utf8_unicode_ci ENGINE = InnoDB':
  SQLSTATE[42S01]: Base table or view already exists: 1050 Table 'autogen_structures' already exists



  [Doctrine\DBAL\Driver\PDOException]
  SQLSTATE[42S01]: Base table or view already exists: 1050 Table 'autogen_structures' already exists
```

I'm actually pretty relieved that it didn't wipe out the data of all of the existing tables, I have experienced this problem before, so I'm assuming it was `orm:schema-tool:update` that caused that problem. On a database with thousands of rows in the table, thats a pretty huge problem because it takes so long to recreate the database from backup files.

Is there a way to create new tables, and ignore existing tables. And also is there a way to update the schema of existing tables without emptying the data in them?

Answer (score 0):

**EDIT:** 
The problem is not solved completely unfortunately. I tried running  again and this time it didn't work, I got this error:

```
  [Doctrine\DBAL\Exception\DriverException]
  An exception occurred while executing 'ALTER TABLE compounds CHANGE id id INT AUTO_INCREMENT NOT NULL':
  SQLSTATE[HY000]: General error: 1833 Cannot change column 'id': used in a foreign key constraint 'FK_5BBEC55AAE76FC
  6F' of table 'chebi_backup.structures'
```

These foreign key constraints were there the first time I ran the command, so I don't understand why its become a problem now when I ran the command a second time. I can't work with doctrine, if it won't let me update the schema. Is there a way around this?

**BEFORE EDIT:**
Problem solved (for MySQL at least). I ran `orm:schema-tool:update --dump-sql --force` on a backup table to see if it would wipe out the data in the existing tables, but it didn't, the table remained perserved. Looking at the query, I see it did not try to create existing tables, it only created the new tables.

The issue I had with data getting wiped out was on an `sqlite` database. This time I'm working with a `MySQL` database. I still don't know why the data was wiped out before, its a bit worrying because if I don't know what happened, it could happen again.

Comment: `--force` will force execute the update. the better way is call without `--force`. `orm:schema-tool:update --dump-sql` it will dump the sql and you can remove these lines which you don't want or can't update easily.